# TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO)

Tags: python, inheritance, typeerror, method-resolution-order

This is the code which I plan to use for my game, but it complains about an MRO error:

```
class Player:
    pass

class Enemy(Player):
    pass

class GameObject(Player, Enemy):
    pass

g = GameObject()
```

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Your `GameObject` is inheriting from `Player` **and** `Enemy`. Because `Enemy` *already* inherits from `Player` Python now cannot determine what class to look methods up on first; either `Player`, or on `Enemy`, which would override things defined in `Player`.

You don't need to name all base classes of `Enemy` here; just inherit from that one class:

```
class GameObject(Enemy):
    pass
```

`Enemy` already includes `Player`, you don't need to include it again.

Answer (score 141):

I'll explain the reason the original code doesn't work.

Python needs to decide in which order to search through (direct and indirect) base classes when looking up an instance attribute / method. It does this by linearizing the inheritance graph, that is by converting the graph of base classes into a sequence, using an algorithm called [C3 or MRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization). The MRO algorithm is the unique algorithm that achieves several desirable properties:

1. each ancestor class appears exactly once
2. a class always appears before its ancestor ("monotonicity")
3. direct parents of the same class should appear in the same order as they are listed in class definition ("consistent local precedence order")
4. if children of class `A` always appear before children of class `B`, then `A` should appear before `B` ("consistent extended precedence order")

With your code, the second constraint requires that `Enemy` appears first; the third constraint requires that `Player` appears first. Since there's no way to satisfy all constraints, python reports that your inheritance hierarchy is illegal.

Your code will work if you switch the order of base classes in `GameObject` like so:

```
class GameObject(Enemy, Player):
    pass
```

This is not just a technical detail. In some (hopefully rare) cases, you might want to think about which class should be used to grab the method you called if the method is defined in multiple classes. The order in which you define base classes affects this choice.

Answer (score 13):

What you wrote is you want a `GameObject` to be both a `Player` and an `Enemy`. But an `Enemy` is already a `Player`. The MRO issue just states that if you had a field `a` in `Player`, asking for this field in a `GameObject` instance would be ambiguous: should it be the `a` from the first `Player` you inherit or the one from the `Player` you inherit through your `Enemy` inheritance?

But are you sure you don't want to use composition instead of inheritance, here?

```
class GameObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = Player()
        self.enemy = Enemy()
```