# Can't import classes Python

Tags: python, class

Here is my code

```
class Game_Events(Setup, Game_Setup):
   def __init__(self):
      super(Game_Events, self).__init__()

      super(Game_Events, self).game_setup(self.map_filename)
```

But when importing the classes I get:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Game_Setup, Setup
```

Here is the **init** of `Setup`:

```
class Setup(object):
   def __init__(self):
    self.HERO_MOVE_SPEED = 20  # pixels per second
    self.MAP_FILENAME = 'resources/tmx/Fesnoria Town.tmx'
    self.MUSIC_FILENAME = "resources/music/Forest_Song.mp3"
```

Here is the **init** of `Game_Setup`:

```
class Game_Setup(Setup):
    def __init__(self):
       super(Game_Setup, self).__init__()
```

I need to import the `Setup` class first because this contains `self.map_filename` which I need for the other class below it.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide the Setup and Game_Setup classes. it seems that they are not using super and it causes havoc...

Comment: but they are really long!

Comment: just the \__init__ and maybe game_setup methods will be fine. as I said, the problem is that those classes misuse "super" in some way...

Comment: Ok I put them up for you

Comment: Why are you inheriting from both the parent and *its* parent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214888/typeerror-cannot-create-a-consistent-method-resolution-order-mro)

Answer (score 2):

`Game_Setup` is a subclass of `Setup`, but `Game_Events` is inheriting from both of them, which is not possible. I guess you should only inherit from `Game_Setup` to make it work.

Comment: But then how can I get access to `Setup` from `Game_Events`

Comment: Since `Game_Setup` inherits from `Setup`, all methods and properties implemented in `Setup` will also be available in `Game_Events`.