# TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases

Tags: python, django

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases StaffRestrictedMixin, StatisticsIndexView
```

I have this type of error, but I can't fix it regardless the other similar questions.

### views.py

```
class StatisticsIndexView(StaffRestrictedMixin, TemplateView):
    model = Statistics()
    template_name = 'loanwolf/statistics/index.html'
    form = StatisticsBaseForm()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StatisticsIndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'applications_by_state': ApplicationsByState(),
            'applications_calendar': ApplicationsCalendar(),
            'new_customers_calendar': NewCustomersCalendar(),
            'statistics': Statistics(),
            'form': StatisticsBaseForm(),
        })
        return context

class StatisticsSubmitView(StaffRestrictedMixin, StatisticsIndexView):
    model = Statistics()
```

What do you suggest to fix that issue?

Comment: You did see that `StaffRestrictedMixin` is now on your base class list twice for `StatisticsSubmitView`? Which one should be first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214888/typeerror-cannot-create-a-consistent-method-resolution-order-mro)