# How to use functions from one class to another in python tkinter

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter

How can I use a function from class `MainPage` in class `AddPart`? I have some functions in class `Mainpage` and I want to use all the functions that are in class `MainPage` in another class `AddPart`.

```
class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) #initialise parent class --> TSS()


    def main_heading(self, heading):
        main_label = tk.Label(self, text = heading, font = LARGE_FONT, fg = 'white', bg = 'RoyalBlue1', width = 1000, height = 4)
        main_label.pack(side = 'top')

    def sub_heading(self, title):
        sub_label = tk.Label(self, text = title, font = MED_FONT, fg = 'RoyalBlue2')
        sub_label.pack(side = 'top', padx = 20, pady = 20)

    def paragraph(self, para):
        paragraph_label = tk.Label(self, text = para, font = SMALL_FONT, fg = 'gray26')
        paragraph_label.pack(side = 'top', padx = 20, pady = 20)

    def top_tool(self):
        toolbar = tk.Frame(self, bg = 'RoyalBlue2')
        AddBtn = tk.Button(toolbar, text = 'ADD', width = 10, bg = 'RoyalBlue2', fg = 'white', borderwidth=0)
        AddBtn.pack(side = 'left', padx = 0, pady = 0)
        RemBtn = tk.Button(toolbar, text = 'REMOVE', width = 10, bg = 'RoyalBlue2', fg = 'white', borderwidth=0)
        RemBtn.pack(side = 'left', padx = 0, pady = 0)
        RevBtn = tk.Button(toolbar, text = 'REVIEW', width = 10, bg = 'RoyalBlue2', fg = 'white', borderwidth=0)
        RevBtn.pack(side = 'left', padx = 0, pady = 0)
        AssignBtn = tk.Button(toolbar, text = 'ASSIGN EVENTS', width = 15, bg = 'RoyalBlue2', fg = 'white', borderwidth=0)
        AssignBtn.pack(side = 'left', padx = 0, pady = 0)
        toolbar.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x')

#-----Second Class------
class AddPart(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.top_tool()
        self.main_heading("Home")

    def main_heading(self, heading):
        main_label = tk.Label(self, text = heading, font = LARGE_FONT, fg = 'white', bg = 'RoyalBlue1', width = 1000, height = 4)
        main_label.pack(side = 'top')
```

Comment: Did you try to inherit the base class?  `class AddPart(tk.Frame, MainPage)`

Comment: It gives me an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maste\Desktop\Python\App\launch_tss.py", line 102, in <module>
    class AddPart(tk.Frame, MainPage):
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Frame, MainPage
>>>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to inherit the base class? 
`class AddPart(MainPage):`

instead of `class AddPart(tk.Frame, MainPage):`, because `MainPage` is already a `tk.Frame`.

Answer (score 0):

### [Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance)

> I want to use all the functions that are in class MainPage in another
>   class AddPart

This is just what inheritance is used for. As [@progmatico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7857466/progmatico) and [@mondlos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6455909/mondlos) pointed out, by inheriting `MainPage` in `AddPart` you will have access to all the base classes functions.

It looks like both of your classes have functions that depend on the class (unless I am misunderstanding the `tk` module you are using), so using something like a static method would not work well.

From your comment, you are getting the `TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO) for bases` error when trying @mondlos suggestion. This is because you are inheriting a type of `tk.Frame` from the `MainPage` that you are also including in `AddPart`. Doing what @progmatico recommends should work. There are several answers suggesting the double inheritance causes this issue at this SO question: [TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214888/typeerror-cannot-create-a-consistent-method-resolution-order-mro)