# Why is this an ambiguous MRO?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

```
class First(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("first")

class Second(First):
    def __init__(self):
        print("second")

class Third(First, Second):
    def __init__(self):
        print("third")
```

<sup>[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277407)</sup>

Why can't Python create a consistent MRO? It seems to me it's pretty clear:

1. Search in First if method does not exist in Third
2. Search in Second if method does not exist in First

But if you try it out:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases First, Second
```

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214888/typeerror-cannot-create-a-consistent-method-resolution-order-mro

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To be "consistent"  the MRO should satisfy these constraints:

1. If a class inherits from multiple superclasses, the ones it lists earlier in the superclass list should come earlier in the MRO than the ones it lists later.
2. Every class in the MRO should come before any of its superclasses.

Your proposed hierarchy does not have any possible ordering meeting these constraints.  Because Third is defined to inherit from First before Second, First should come before Second in the MRO.  But because Second inherits from First, Second should come before First in the MRO.  This contradiction cannot be reconciled.

You can read more about the precise method Python uses to compute the MRO, which is called the [C3 linearization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization).

Comment: [C3 linearisation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) is a must-read.

Comment: Spectacular explanation. It makes more sense now after reading the goals for consistency.

Answer (score 5):

Python internally thinks not to have super class before sub-class.

According to your code. After Scanning or loading the classes, Python thinks the method resolution has to be:

```
Third -> Second -> First
```

Here, **First** is the super class of **Second**.

But while executing, after checking **Third** it confronts **First** which is the super class of **Second**.

Hence the TypeError.

```
class Third(First, Second): # Wrong
class Third(Second, First): # Correct
```

Answer (score 1):

If we apply the C3 linearization algorithm:

i) take the head of the first list.

ii) if this head is not in the tail of any of the other lists, then add it to the linearization of C and remove it from the lists in the merge

iii) otherwise look at the head of the next list and take it if it is a good head

iv) Then repeat the operation until all the class is removed or it is impossible to find good heads.

O : is the object class

L[First] = First O

L[Second] = Second + merge(L[First], First)

Now solving L[Second]

L[Second] = Second + merge(FirstO, First)

First is the head in list FirstO and in the list First, so it is a good head.

L[Second] = Second + First + merge(O)

O is the only head in the list and it is good head

L[Second] = Second + First + O

L[Second] = Second First O

L[Third] = Third + merge(L[First], L[Second], FirstSecond)

Now solving L[Third]

L[Third] = Third + merge(FirstO, SecondFirstO, FirstSecond)

L[Third] = Third + impossible to find good heads.

First is the head in the list FirstO but it is the tail in the list SecondFirstO, Second is the head in the list SecondFirstO but it is the tail in the list FirstSecond and O is tail in both the list FirstO, SecondFirstO so it is not possible to find good heads.