# How can I create an abstract class that inherits from an abstract class in Python?

Tags: python, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

I'd like to define an abstract class which inherits from another abstract class.

```
class DataBuffer(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffered_data = {}

class IMUDataBuffer(ABC, DataBuffer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(IMUDataBuffer, self).__init__()

    def update(self, message):
        timestamp = message['ts']
        x_val, y_val, z_val = message[self.message_key]
        self.buffered_data[timestamp] = (x_val, y_val, z_val)

class GyroscopeDataBuffer(IMUDataBuffer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GyroscopeDataBuffer, self).__init__()
        self.message_key = 'gy'

class AccelerometerDataBuffer(IMUDataBuffer):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super(AccelerometerDataBuffer, self).__init__()
        self.message_key = 'ac'
```

In this example, the IMUDataBuffer should inherit methods from DataBuffer, but it itself will not ever be instantiated, and thus should be an abstract class.

This is the error that I receive with the above code:

```
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO) for bases ABC, DataBuffer
```

As a cheap work around, I can define a message_key in the IMUDatabuffer, but this feels sloppy to me, as really the IMUDataBuffer shouldn't have a message_key property.

```
class IMUDataBuffer(DataBuffer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(IMUDataBuffer, self).__init__()
        self.message_key = None
```

What is the proper way to handle the inheritance here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose to remove the ABC in IMUDataBuffer parent list as DataBuffer already has ABC as parent.

```
ABC -> DataBuffer -> IMUDataBuffer -> Gyroscope
                                   -> Accelerometer
```

The code would look like this:

```
class ABC:
    pass

class DataBuffer(ABC):  # <-- brings already all stuff from ABC
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffered_data = {}

class IMUDataBuffer(DataBuffer):  # <-- ABC removed here
    def __init__(self):
        super(IMUDataBuffer, self).__init__()

    [...]
```

Then the error disappears.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, but I'm getting an "unresolved attribute reference" from pycharm for the message_key variable. Is it possible that this class still isn't truly being recognized as an ABC?

Comment: You can inherit from multiple classes in Python. But in this case it's not necessary.

Comment: @KevinKing what is the class definition of ABC? It's right that self.message_key does not exist in IMUDataBuffer, Pycharm is totally right.

Comment: ABC is the AbstractBaseClass in the default abc library. ```from abc import ABC```

Comment: ABC looked to me like foo, bar, 123... I'll take a look at the docs. Thanks, @KevinKing !

Answer (score 0):

Here is fix -

```
from abc import *

class DataBuffer(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffered_data = {}

class IMUDataBuffer(DataBuffer, ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        super(IMUDataBuffer, self).__init__()

    def update(self, message):
        timestamp = message['ts']
        x_val, y_val, z_val = message[self.message_key]
        self.buffered_data[timestamp] = (x_val, y_val, z_val)
```

Also refer this for detail explaination - 
[Why is this an ambiguous MRO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808926/why-is-this-an-ambiguous-mro?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This seems close, but when I try to instantiate the GyroscopeDataBuffer class, I get a ```TypeError: __new__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'name', 'bases', and 'namespace' ```

Comment: I have updated the code. I was using python 2.7. Corrected it for python 3. See your code working here - https://repl.it/repls/DetailedAngryInstitution

Answer (score 0):

In Python, simply inheriting from ABC doesn't prevent instantiation. This works fine:

```
from abc import ABC

class Foo(ABC):
    pass

foo = Foo()
```

Instantiation will only raise an error if there are unimplemented `abstractmethod`s.

Your intermediate class doesn't have to inherit from ABC, just from `DataBuffer`. As long as there are unimplemented `abstractmethod`s instantiation will fail.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Foo(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def do_thing(self):
        pass

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

bar = Bar()  # Instantiation raises TypeError because Bar does not implement do_thing
```

Since Bar inherits from Foo which is an abstract class, Bar is also an abstract class:

```
>>> type(Foo)
<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>
>>> type(Bar)
<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>
```

Compare with some other random class:

```
>>> class Baz:
>>>    pass
>>> type(Baz)
<class 'type'>
```