# Error when trying to call the constructor of super class in multiple inheritance. What's happening behind the scenes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Reporting from A")

    def feature1(self):
        return "feature1 from A working!"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Reporting from B")

    def feature2(self):
        return  "feature2 from B working!"

class C(A,B):                               # multiple inheritance
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Reporting from C")

    def feature3(self):
        return  "feature3 from C working!"


c = C()
```

Error message:

```
class C(A,B):                               # multiple inheritance

TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases A, B
```

But when I change the order of inheritance from `(A,B)` to `(B,A)` it works fine.**

Comment: Duplicate: [TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214888/typeerror-cannot-create-a-consistent-method-resolution-order-mro)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I didn't know who to relate my post to the already existing solution.