# How can I do to create an heritage for my class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Hello I am trying to use the library PyQt5 but I got a problem. Below is the code :

```
class figure(QWidget, QtCore.QObject, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # My class
```

I got this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
```

order (MRO) for bases QWidget, QObject, QMainWindow

How can I do to solve this error ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: I don't understand why you want those 3 classes since the QMainWindow is a QWidget, and the QWidget is a QObject, so it is enough to inherit from QMainWindow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from inheriting both `QWidget`, and `QtWidgets.QMainWindow`. `QtWidgets.QMainWindow` [already inherits from](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) `QWidget` causing the error.  Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214888/typeerror-cannot-create-a-consistent-method-resolution-order-mro) for a simple example of the problem. Try dropping the `QWidget`.